# twitter url of version 1.1 for developing windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, twitter-oauth

i don't find an exact json URL for developing twitter app on windows phone 7.
please can u give me an example or perfect URL for version 1.1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mee to also working for same thing Now getting 215 bad Auth Error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) are your best friend.

I am assuming you are looking for this:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

You will still need authentication for this call (read: [OAuth](http://oauth.net/about/)).

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
This the error i am getting running twitter url.

Comment: And your auth implementation is...?

Comment: i am just checking the url in the browser itself. So i am getting this error . Is their any other method for getting the json data from url.
I am new to the windows phone 8.

Comment: That won't work. You need to have an OAuth layer with it. Notice: **Authentication Required** in the sidebar.